# Does using CloudFront just to enable https make sense?

Tags: amazon-web-services, https, amazon-cloudfront

If I have an EC2 instance, running a web app (HTTP), and I have an Amazon-provided SSL certificate, I can use CloudFront to make the EC2 instance accessible via HTTPS, handling the certificate automatically.
Is this a legitimate use of CloudFront, or should this be done differently?

Comment: did you try using an Application Load Balancer? depending on your use case perhaps CF is overkill

Comment: @OscarDeLeón I looked at ALB, however the base price seems pretty high for this particular instance - the ALB would cost about as much as the instance itself.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes using CloudFront is a legitimate way to enable https, and (as iBug pointed out in comments) can reduce your bandwidth egress costs a little. Another option is to use an application balancer, which integrates with AWS Certificate Manager (ACM) to enable https.

A lower cost method is to install a certificate directly on your EC2 instance using [Lets Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) and some of their compatible software. You can't use an ACM certificate with just an EC2 instance. [Certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/) is a common piece of software used to request LE certs.

Comment: Thanks for these pointers, I will be checking out Lets Encrypt

Comment: Using CloudFront generally *reduces* your cost if the origin is an EC2 instance (or S3). EC2 and S3 charges a flat egress price while CloudFront charges "use more, pay less", and it even starts lower (8.5¢ for US / Canada vs EC2 9¢).

Comment: Thanks iBug I added your comment to the answer. AWS bandwidth is pretty expensive either way, for some sites I use an external caching CDN which can reduce costs more.